# Pseudo code for instruction description

Tags: c++, c

I am just trying to fiddle around what is the best and shortest way to describe two simple instructions with C-like pseudo code. The extract instruction is defined as follows:

```
extract rd, rs, imm
```

This instruction extracts the appropriate byte from the 32-bit source register rs and
right justifies it in the destination register. The byte is specified by imm and thus
can take the values 0 (for the least-significant byte) and 3 (for the most-significant byte).

```
rd = 0x0;  // zero-extend result, ie to make sure bits 31 to 8 are set to zero in the result
rd = (rs && (0xff << imm)) >> imm; // this extracts the approriate byte and stores it in rd
```

The insert instruction can be regarded as the inverse operation and it takes a right justified byte from the source register rs and deposits it in the appropriate byte of the
destination register rd; again, this byte is determined by the value of imm

```
tmp = 0x0 XOR (rs << imm)) // shift the byte to the appropriate byte determined by imm
rd = (rd && (0x00 << imm)) // set appropriate byte to zero in rd
rd = rd XOR tmp            // XOR the byte into the destination register
```

This looks all a bit horrible, so I wonder if there is a little bit a more elegant way to
describe this bahaviour in C-like style ;)

Many thanks,
Claus

Comment: Sorry, but “C-like pseudo code” is an oxymoron. The whole reason for pseudo-code is to abstract away from the computer by using prose and/or mathematical notation to describe operations instead of formal syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Extract:

```
rd = (rs >> (imm * 8)) & 0xff
```

Insert:

```
rd = (rd & ~(0xff << (imm * 8))) | ((rs & 0xff) << (imm * 8))
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I make life harder than it is :P

Comment: I think the first `rs` in the insert line should be `rd`.

Comment: +1: I answered with formulae like yours, but falsely as I forgot the * 8. and the protection mask ... Credit to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you mean '&' (bit operator AND) instead of '&&' (logical AND). The XOR bitwise operator in C is '^'

```
rd = 0x0;
rd = (rs & (0xff << imm)) >> imm;

tmp = 0x0 ^ (rs << imm));
rd = (rd & (0x00 << imm));
rd = rd ^ tmp;
```

Second, it is simpler to do something like :

```
rd = (rs >> (imm * 8)) & 0xFF;
```

and for the second part :

```
rd = (~(0xFF << (imm * 8)) & rd) | ((rs & 0xFF) << (imm * 8));
```

The first part create a mask with '1' bits everywhere but in the interesting byte the AND (&) set this byte to '0' and then you add your rs byte. It is not optimised but you see the point.

Edit : I just see Matthew answer. I've misread, imm is in bytes not bits, so as he points out a *8 is needed. I've corrected the formula. He is right too to mask rd with 0xFF to be sure that rs most significant bytes are not taken into account ...

my2c